# Memory leak when unpickling pandas/numpy in Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pickle

I am running into a memory leak and have trouble debugging it. The first part describes what happens when I generate the sample data at runtime, the second when sample data is cached in a file.

1) When I unpickle a collection (in this example a `dict`) of pandas (version 1.0) `dataframes`, within a function I experience a memory leak. The memory usage goes from 131 MB at the start to 2,075 at the end (see first and last line in screenshot), even after calling gc.collect(). The code is shown below. The screenshot additionally shows the output of `tracemalloc`.

[image]

Since this is running inside a function I would have expected that all local variables will be cleared on return. Interestingly, when I `del` data inside the function, the problem goes away for the case where I generate the sample data inside the function.

[image]

```
def print_process_mem_usage(do_print=True):
    import os
    import psutil
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    mem_usg = process.memory_info().rss/1.e6
    if do_print:
        print(f'{mem_usg:3,.0f} MB')
    else:
        return mem_usg


def func():
    import pandas as pd
    import pickle
    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.util.testing.getTimeSeriesData(nper=60_000))
    data = {ix: df.copy() for ix in range(1000)}
    stream = pickle.dumps(data)
    # del data

    print_process_mem_usage()
    out = pickle.loads(stream)
    return out

def trace_memory(func):
    import tracemalloc
    import gc
    tracemalloc.start()
    print_process_mem_usage()
    out = func()
    snapshot1 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
    del out
    print_process_mem_usage()
    snapshot2 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
    tracemalloc.stop()
    gc.collect()
    print('snapshot 1')
    for stat in snapshot1.statistics('lineno')[:10]:
        print(stat)
    print('snapshot 2')
    for stat in snapshot2.statistics('lineno')[:10]:
        print(stat)
    print_process_mem_usage()
```

2) Even worse, when I write the data to file, like so

```
def write_sample_data_to_file():
    with open('/tmp/output1', 'wb') as f:
        import pickle
        import numpy as np
        import pandas as pd
        df = pd.DataFrame(pd.util.testing.getTimeSeriesData(nper=60_000))
        stream = {ix: df.copy() for ix in range(1000)}
        stream = pickle.dumps(stream)
        f.write(stream)

write_sample_data_to_file()
```

and then call trace_memory on the following loader function:

```
def func():
    with open('/tmp/output1', 'rb') as f:
        stream = f.read()

    print_process_mem_usage()
    import pickle
    out = pickle.loads(stream)
    del stream

    return out
```

Even though I am deleting `stream` in this function, the memory is not reliably freed. Repeatedly calling the function (sometimes it requires a restart of the kernel as well) eventually brings back the problem again (around 2GB extra memeory usage).

Any ideas what is going on or how to further track down the problem?

Comment: Problem both in python 3.6 and 3.7.6

Comment: I believe the issue might be addressed in this PEP: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0574/